# How can I tell when a javascript form method=post is finished in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript form in a react app as such:

```
      <form action = "http://localhost:3002/REVIEW" method = "post">
      <input type = "hidden" name ="CurrRev"  value = {this.state.fileContent}/>
      <input type = "hidden" name = "DT" value = {this.state.curTime}/>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.showFile(e)} />
      <br></br>
      <input type = "text" name ="REVNAME" placeholder="Enter a name for your Review" value = {this.state.RevName} onChange={this.handleRevName}/>
      <br></br>
      <input type="submit" className="submit" value="Create New Review" />
```

And I need to update a state in the react component called "step", only after the form is submitted.
I'm not interested in success or failure, ONLY if the form submission is done. Is there a generally accepted way to confirm a form is finished?

Comment: If the form submission occurs, your page is torn down and replaced with the `action` page. Are you doing something to prevent that happening? If not, the answer is: You know when it was submitted when the action page is loaded. (Er, with `referer` set to the original page. Probably.) :-D

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt response! So this is posting the contents of a file to a database on AWS through a local API i'm using. After a successful post, the contents are hosted in my database, and I want to update step so that the user is directed to a confirmation screen that does other work on the database. Everything is functioning as expected, but when I include the step update inside the submit(onSubmit={this.state.stepUpdate} the form isn't submitted. I may be misunderstanding something about how the javascript form processes.

Comment: Ran out of chars:
So on clicking submit, the functions work as expected, and my database receives the info. Then the page simply hangs.

Comment: Further, I've left it hanging, and see that the contents are then pushed to the database AGAIN, after an unknown amount of time.
EDIT: it then eventually crashes the page by referring to the API's URL

Comment: Further info, I see what you were talking about in regards to the tear-down and rebuild. I forgot I had disabled my node.js API response from post method to test something a while back.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that my question was inherently flawed, based on my misunderstanding of the javascript form submission. I will be learning AJAX to overcome this misconception and perform the submission and update to states as I expected the behavior to be from the javascript for submission. Many thanks to T.J. Crowder for assisting me; his answer pointed me down the path of research I needed. To anyone who finds this in the future; make sure you understand what you're using in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileReader onload methods to set the state with the file content and check  the file content length to step forward.
Also you can check all other input fields to be empty along with the file content on every input's onChange method.

You can find this useful to handle files using File Reader in React [ReactJS File Reader](https://youtu.be/Z4SDez4WsVQ)